# Increase the user load on runtime in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

Is it possible to increase the user load on runtime.For example below is the setup

```
No of request = 3
No of thread = 5
Ramp-up period = 1
Loop Count = 1
Constant timer in request 2 & 3 of 3000 ms
```

Q1. is is possible to increase the user load 5-10 while running request 2 after wait?

Please let me know is it possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options of "increasing" the load during the test run:

1. Using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer). Despite the word "Constant" it its name the target throughput doesn't have to be constant given you define it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P). Once done you will be able to amend the desired throughput using i.e. [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) while your test is running. You can even do it outside the test via i.e. [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server), check out [How to Adjust the RPS in Your JMeter Test via the Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-adjust-the-rps-in-your-jmeter-test-via-the-command-line) guide for detailed instructions
2. In JMeter 3.2 and higher you have possibility to add more threads to the Thread Groups during the runtime using the same "JMeter Properties" approach. Alternative option is using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the code like:

   ```
   ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(0, ctx.getEngine())
   ```

   where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for referenced methods description.